# How to call my factory service correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I am getting the 'is not a function' error when trying to invoke my service. NgResource is already injected. What am I doing wrong?

**controller.js:**

```
app.controller('controllerA', ['$scope', 'CustomizingService', 
    function($scope, CustomizingService) {
        $scope.cust = CustomizingService.Customizing.squares({numberOf: 2, valid: true});
}]);
```

**service.js:**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('ST_CCG').factory('CustomizingService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        //var url = config.CustomizingAPI_Url + '/Customizing/:link/';
        var url = 'http://localhost:54483/BusinessService.svc/:link/';

        return {
            Customizing: $resource(url,  {
                squares: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: { link: 'GetSquares', numberOf: '@numberOf', valid: @valid },
                    isArray: true },
                 circles: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: { link: 'GetCircles',  valid: true },
                    isArray: true }
            })
        };
    }]);
})();
```

**EDIT**

I am using chrome debugger and got following error:
*TypeError: CustomizingService.Customizing.orders is not a function*

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('ST_CCG', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', 
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/menu', {
                    templateUrl: 'Modules/Menu/view.html',
                    controller: 'controllerA'
                }).
                when('/orders', {
                    templateUrl: 'Modules/Orders/view.html',
                    controller: 'controllerB'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }
]);
```

**index.html:**

```
...
<!--MODOLE + CONTROLLER Resources-->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="service.js"></script>
<script src="modules/menu/controller.js"></script>
<script src="modules/orders/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ST_CCG">

<a href="#/menu">Menu</a>
<a href="#/orders">Orders</a>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

Comment: were do you get the error ?

Comment: when loading the site, let me update my question. I am using the chrome debugger.

Comment: I always worry when I see `angular.module(onlyOneArgument)`. Seems to be the cause of many problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you're passing your *actions* in where the *default params* go. Change it to

```
Customizing: $resource(url, {valid: true}, {
    squares: // etc
```

I used `valid: true` as the default params as you appear to use it in both actions.

Comment: Got this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://localhost:54483/BusinessService.svc... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. HTTP status code 500. I am using webstorm for frontend and visual studio for backend. I started the service via IIS server. Can you help me?

Comment: Your API needs CORS headers though that might just be because it's erroring. Check your API logs

Comment: Using the Chrome's CORS extension now. Currently I am getting the error Error in resource configuration for action `customers`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object when invoking the method. Changin isArray: false is not helping.

Comment: I opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383930/how-to-load-my-webservice-resource, please take a look on it if you find time